# How can I automatically enable large text when logging in to the ubuntu session?

Tags: gnome, fonts, startup, accessibility, hdpi

I enabled the large text option in accessibility menu because I have Full-HD screen. The problem is why the setting reverts itself back to "non-large" mode after I restart my PC? It's funny because the switch in settings is set on, but some UI elements like top panel are small but apps like Chrome are enlarged. I use ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Can you write me a correct script for that setting so I can paste it to startup applications so it runs when I login into the system. I couldn't find it on internet?

Comment: You are victim of a current bug in mutter. See the duplicate question for a command that you can add to your startup applications until this is fixed.